# Is there a grammar rule telling when to drop or not to drop a definite article before names?

Tags: grammar, definite-article

Is there any rule in English regulating when I can omit the definite article before names?

Here is the list of banks of Taiwan [taken from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_banks_in_Taiwan) (no need to read through it, just go ahead and scroll to the bottom):

> Chunghwa Post
>
> Bank of Taiwan
>
> Land Bank of Taiwan
>
> Taiwan Cooperative Bank
>
> First Commercial Bank
>
> Hua Nan Commercial Bank
>
> Chang Hwa Bank
>
> Citibank Taiwan
>
> Shanghai Commercial and Savings Bank
>
> Taipei Fubon Bank
>
> Taipei Star Bank
>
> Cathay United Bank
>
> Export-Import Bank of the Republic of China
>
> Bank of Kaohsiung
>
> Mega International Commercial Bank
>
> O-Bank
>
> Taiwan Business Bank
>
> Standard Chartered Bank Taiwan
>
> Taichung Bank
>
> King's Town Bank
>
> Hwatai Bank
>
> Taiwan Shin Kong Commercial Bank
>
> Sunny Bank
>
> Bank of Panshin
>
> COTA Commercial Bank
>
> Union Bank of Taiwan
>
> Far Eastern international Bank
>
> Yuanta Bank
>
> Bank SinoPac
>
> E.SUN Commercial Bank
>
> KGI Bank
>
> Taishin International Bank
>
> Jih Sun International Commercial Bank
>
> EnTie Commercial Bank
>
> CTBC Bank - China Trust

As it can be seen, none of these names contain definite article "the". However, if you go to the respective wiki page of each bank, you will see that almost all of those pages start with the article 'the' placed right before the bank's name. Later in the text, however, the article is sometimes omitted.

So, is there any rule in English telling me whether I should say:

> Jack usually transfers his money to Chang Hwa Bank.

or

> Jack usually transfers his money to **the** Chang Hwa Bank.

?

Comment: The articles are usually dropped from titles for sake of brevity .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are encountering Wikipedia-specific conventions on article names and usage. See, among other places, the administrative guideline page [Wikipedia:Naming conventions (companies)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Naming_conventions_(companies)) where it is said:

> In some cases, leading articles (usually The) and suffixes (such as Company, International, Group, and so forth) are an integral part of the company name and should be included as specified by the company, especially when necessary for disambiguation (for example, *The Walt Disney Company* and *The Coca-Cola Company*). In other instances, such as with *JPMorgan Chase & Co*., the common usage of *JPMorgan Chase* is preferred.

...

> Regardless of the article title, the first sentence of the article should normally begin with the full legal name of the company ...

Thus, the usage in the titles and first paragraphs of Wikipedia articles may not be a good guide to more general usage.

When "the" is part of the formal name of a bank, as it often is, it will be used in formal contexts. Even when it is not, a definite article may be used for emphasis, or for a more formal style. But in informal contexts, and particularly in news articles and headlines where brevity is of value, any article is often dropped.

Comment: Thank you! "But in informal contexts, and particularly in news articles and headlines where brevity is of value, any article is often dropped" - So, just to make sure, I can drop the article from my sentence about Jack then (it is spoken by his friend), right?

Comment: @brilliant  yes in informal speech that would be fine.